# QGIS "freeze(?)" on Windows 10 when using color sampling tool?

Tags: qgis

On the Windows 10 computers in our internal IT infrasctructure QGIS freezes when trying to use color sample tool. We use 2.18.21 and I never observed this behaviour before on clients outside our infrastructure. No color is sampled when clicking somewhere with the pipette cursor and the whole windows becomes almost inoperable, apart from killing qgis task in the task manager.

I just observed the following behaviour:

I Select 'sample color'. Pipette cursor apears and can be moved around. But clicking somwhere does not chose a color to by sampled nor focus is given back to 'Select color' dialogue. When doing a Ctrl-Alt-Del, locking the workstation and sign in to the workstation again, the color is selected and focus given back to 'Select color' dialogue.

I just installed QGIS 2.18.24 LTR and QGIS 3.2.1 in c:\tmp with OSGeo4w installer and observed the same behaviour with 2.18.24 but not with 3.2.1, where color sampling works as expected.

What might cause this behaviour?